# Shift up range to overlap empty cells with user input application

Tags: excel, vba

[image]I have this range of cells which  i want to shift up to eliminate those empty rows of cells. I have done this with the use of an input box so that user can select the range which has such issues. I tried this code but after running it,  the row that i wanted to shift up , it disappeared.

```
Sub Shiftup()


Dim rng As Range
Dim inp As Range


Set inp = Selection
On Error Resume Next
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Range to Shift Up", Type:=8)
 On Error GoTo 0
    If TypeName(rng) <> "Range" Then
        Exit Sub
    Else

rng.Select

rng.Rows.Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: Tried your code here, it works. Did you make sure you are entering correctly the RANGE-TO-REMOVE? (A6:C7 in your example?)

Comment: Ah I see, according to your code, you should enter the range to remove, not the range to shift up!

Comment: if you are using this `Set rng = Application.InputBox("Range to Shift Up", Type:=8)` then use `Rows(rng.Row-1).Delete Shift:=xlShiftUp` Assuming that you are selecting the top most row of the range that you want to shift

Comment: There's a possibility that all of the horizontal cells will not be selected thereby staggering the cells. Might be better to use `rng.EntireRow.Delete`.

Comment: Thank you everyone. I realised the mistake! heh  @A.S.H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Set rng = Application.InputBox("Range to delete", Type:=8)
```

and BTW, you do not need to select the range, the statement `rng.select` can only cause you trouble (i.e. if the worksheet is not active) and it achieves nothing in your code.

Comment: True... Better to be specific :)

Comment: It is an interactive dashboard which users use, hence i cant hardcode it as if users face a similar problem on a different range of cells it would be come difficult! @SiddharthRout